# React-Select v2 comma separated search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select, react-select

Is there a way with react-select v2 to search for multiple values at once? Like I could have my user paste in a list of comma or space separated values and items matching those results would display in the dropdown.

Example react-select (we call them item pickers):

```
<StyledFormItemPicker
          className="emailPicker"
          filterKeys={['label']}
          label="email picker"
          value={emailPickerValue}
          onChange={value => onEmailPickerChange(value)}
          items={users}
          isMulti={true}
        />
```

onChange code:

```
// allow user to pass in comma separated list to search
export const onEmailPickerChange = props => event => {
  event.persist();
  // split event (value) on space or comma
  // push to an array
  // set that array of strings as the value and see all results?
};
```

Comment: For exemple if the user searches for `blue, red` it might return options like `deep blue`, `red`, `indigo blue` etc ?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to achieve your feature I would use the props `filterOption`.

```
const filterOption = ({ label, value }, string) => {
  if(string === "") return true;

  const parsedString = string.split(/[, ]+/);
  for (const string of parsedString) {
    // Need to check of string is not empty after the split
    if (string !== "" && (label.includes(string) || value.includes(string)))
      return true;
  } 
  return false;
};
```

The idea is to split the input value by either space or comma (in the example above I did the combination of those two options) and to apply the regular filtering `react-select` is doing on each instance.

Live example available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-filter-multiple-search-option-52byw).

Comment: That's great! That was exactly what I was looking for. The only issue I'm running into now, and seeing the same thing happen in the demo, is that when nothing is typed in it doesn't show all the items in the dropdown anymore it says "no options"

Comment: Let me fix try to fix that

Comment: I've updated the code with `if(string === "") return true;` so the first time you click you'll still see all the options.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!